# How can I tell cppCheck to NOT treat a function as an allocation function?

Tags: c++, cppcheck

I've got a codebase using Qt that I want run cppCheck on, and I'd like to make it run reasonably clean (suppress or fix most of the errors).

I have this function addResultLable:

```
QLabel * TestScreen::addResultLabel(const QString& labelText, int x, int y)
{
    QLabel *pLabel = new QLabel(baseFrame);
    pLabel->setText(labelText);
    pLabel->setGeometry(x, y, TEST_RESULT_WIDTH, TEST_RESULT_HEIGHT);
    pLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    return pLabel;
}
```

And I call it thusly:
    addResultLabel("Packets", TEST_RESULT_OFFSET, nextY);
    nextY += TEST_RESULT_HEIGHT;
    m_packets = addResultLabel("0", TEST_RESULT_OFFSET, nextY);

cppCheck comes up with the `(error) Return value of allocation function addResultLabel is not stored.` on that first call.

While true, it's not relevant: the QLabel is linked properly to it's parent in the `new QLabel(baseFrame)` call, so it doesn't actually matter if the caller of `addResultLabel` keeps it or not. There's a number of these calls, and I don't want to supress at each call site.

What I would like to do is tell cppCheck that `addResultLabel` is in fact NOT an allocation function, so that it stops checking it's callers.

I've hunted through the manual, and while I can see how to ADD a new allocation function, I can't see how to tell cppCheck NOT to treat a function as an allocation function.

Comment: If you don't ever store the return value, just change it to `void TestScreen::addResultLabel(...)`. Of course, that doesn't work if you use the return value some times, but not always...

Comment: @twalberg - yea, sadly we do use it sometimes so that's not an option for us.

Answer (score 3):

I am a Cppcheck developer.

That is a false positive. It should be fixed in Cppcheck.

I created a ticket about it in the Cppcheck issue tracker:
http://trac.cppcheck.net/ticket/6775

Comment: Any news on that one? It seems that even suppressing it from the command line with --suppress= leakReturnValNotUsed, doesn't work because the executable returns with error which fails our automated builds.

Comment: Sorry, no progress. However there is a small bounty on fixing it nowadays. We have a bounty for old unfixed defects.

Comment: If it is suppressed then the exitcode should be 0. Do you use --exitcode-suppressions ?

Comment: No I don't. Here is the full line:
cppcheck --enable=warning --enable=portability --enable=style --enable=performance --suppress=leakReturnValNotUsed --error-exitcode=253 --inline-suppr --std=c++11 -j8 --xml Source 2> cppcheck.xml

Comment: the exitcode should be 0 then. so there is a bug. however I fail to reproduce for me the exitcode is 0 if it is suppressed. I use 64-bit debian. I wonder if you can try to compile cppcheck and debug this. please come to the cppcheck IRC channel if you want to talk about this, url is http://webchat.freenode.net and channel is #cppcheck .

Comment: After some additional investigation it turns out I get exit code 0 when I run the same command without "-j 8", so the bug has to do with multithreading.

Comment: Can you reproduce that with latest cppcheck also (released a few days ago)? It sounds related to http://trac.cppcheck.net/ticket/5746

Comment: Hi. Just to warn that it might not be fixed yet: `if (NULL == file_path()) {...}`, and the warning: "Cppcheck: (error) leakReturnValNotUsed: Return value of allocation function 'file_path' is not stored." - unless this is intended behaviour? (If it is, why? I'm partially beginner on C, but I don't care if the value gets stored or not here, it's just a check)